# Issue Importing AudioSegment from Pydub in Python

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

I'm trying to import pydub into a project and am getting the following errors:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wave.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pydub import AudioSegment
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydub/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .audio_segment import AudioSegment
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 7, in <module>
    import wave
  File "/Users/Sim/Desktop/Audio Wave/wave.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pydub import AudioSegment
ImportError: cannot import name 'AudioSegment'`

I installed pydub with no issues, so not really sure what the problem may be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did not like the name `wave.py` for the file. Gave it a new name and all good now.